# scipy.stats.norm for array of values

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, gaussian, probability-density

I'd like to calculate the probability values for an array of values, using Gaussians with different means and variances. For e.g., I can do this

```
scipy.stats.norm.pdf(9, [10, 12, 14], [2, 4, 5])
```

and it gives me the pdf values for the value 9, for the three different Gaussians - N(10, 2), N(12, 4) and N(14, 5). I'd like to do the same for multiple values, like so

```
scipy.stats.norm.pdf([8,9], [10, 12, 14], [2, 4, 5])
```

where the pdf values for 8 and 9 are calculated for the three Gaussians and I'd get a 2D array as a return.

Questions

1. Is there anything in numpy or scipy that'll allow me to do this?
2. If the answer to #1 is no, how can I accomplish this without using a for loop (please note, I looked at vectorize in scipy, but it uses a for loop under the hood). I need to avoid a for loop since I'll be doing this on millions of values, for several Gaussians.

Comment: You may have to use a for loop, but if you only have "several" Gaussians then the loop could be short.  Basically you could create all your Gaussians and then do `for distrib in all_my_distributions: distrib.pdf(all_my_values)`.  So it will be vectorized along the millions-of-values dimension.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `pdf` method will use numpy [broadcasting](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/ufuncs.html#broadcasting), so in your second example, you can make the first argument an array (actually, "array-like" is sufficient) with shape (2, 1).  An array with shape (2, 1) that is broadcast with an array with shape (3,) results in an array with shape (2, 3):

```
In [14]: norm.pdf([[8],[9]], [10, 12, 14], [2, 4, 5])
Out[14]: 
array([[ 0.12098536,  0.06049268,  0.03883721],
       [ 0.17603266,  0.07528436,  0.04839414]])
```

Comment: Can you add an example for the multivariate normal PDF?

Comment: To clarify, I mean evaluating several multivariate normal PDFs, each with a different mean and coviariance, at multiple points

Comment: @RylanSchaeffer 2 yrs late but I vectorized this exact use case: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75358177/13264334