# Vectorized implementation for `numpy.random.multivariate_normal`

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to use `numpy.random.multivariate_normal` to generate multiple samples where each sample is drawn from a multivariate Normal distribution with a different `mean` and `cov`. For example, if I would like to draw 2 samples, I tried

```
from numpy import random as rand

means = np.array([[-1., 0.], [1., 0.]])
covs = np.array([np.identity(2) for k in xrange(2)]) 
rand.multivariate_normal(means, covs)
```

but this results in `ValueError: mean must be 1 dimensional`. Do I have to do a for loop for this? I thought that for functions like `rand.binomial` this is possible.

Comment: Does multivariate normal theory allow for any sort of scaling?  That is generate values with one set of parameters, and scale them to other sets?  I'm a little rusty on that math, but I think it's possible in 1d.

Comment: Since this function is `builtin` (compiled) iteration on several sets of parameters shouldn't be that slow.  Have you tried timings?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As @hpaulj suggested, you can generate samples from the standard multivariate normal distribution, and then use, say, `einsum` and/or broadcasting to transform the samples.  The scaling is done by multiplying the standard sample points by the square root of the covariance matrix.  In the following, I use `scipy.linalg.sqrtm` to compute the matrix square root, and  `numpy.einsum` to do the matrix multiplication.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.linalg import sqrtm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


# Sequence of means
means = np.array([[-15., 0.], [15., 0.], [0., 0.]])
# Sequence of covariance matrices.  Must be the same length as means.
covs = np.array([[[ 3, -1],
                  [-1,  2]],
                 [[ 1,  2],
                  [ 2,  5]],
                 [[ 1,  0],
                  [ 0,  1]]])
# Number of samples to generate for each (mean, cov) pair.
nsamples = 4000

# Compute the matrix square root of each covariance matrix.
sqrtcovs = np.array([sqrtm(c) for c in covs])

# Generate samples from the standard multivariate normal distribution.
dim = len(means[0])
u = np.random.multivariate_normal(np.zeros(dim), np.eye(dim),
                                  size=(len(means), nsamples,))
# u has shape (len(means), nsamples, dim)

# Transform u.
v = np.einsum('ijk,ikl->ijl', u, sqrtcovs)
m = np.expand_dims(means, 1)
t = v + m

# t also has shape (len(means), nsamples, dim).
# t[i] holds the nsamples sampled from the distribution with mean means[i]
# and covariance cov[i].

plt.subplot(2, 1, 1)
plt.plot(t[...,0].ravel(), t[...,1].ravel(), '.', alpha=0.02)
plt.axis('equal')
plt.xlim(-25, 25)
plt.ylim(-8, 8)
plt.grid()

# Make another plot, where we generate the samples by passing the given
# means and covs to np.random.multivariate_normal.  This plot should look
# the same as the first plot.
plt.subplot(2, 1, 2)
p0 = np.random.multivariate_normal(means[0], covs[0], size=nsamples)
p1 = np.random.multivariate_normal(means[1], covs[1], size=nsamples)
p2 = np.random.multivariate_normal(means[2], covs[2], size=nsamples)

plt.plot(p0[:,0], p0[:,1], 'b.', alpha=0.02)
plt.plot(p1[:,0], p1[:,1], 'g.', alpha=0.02)
plt.plot(p2[:,0], p2[:,1], 'r.', alpha=0.02)
plt.axis('equal')
plt.xlim(-25, 25)
plt.ylim(-8, 8)
plt.grid()
```

[image: plot]

This method might not be any faster that looping over the `means` and `covs` arrays and calling `multivariate_normal` once for each pair (mean, cov).  The case where this method would give the most benefit is when you have *many* different means and covariances and are generating a small number of samples per pair.  And even then, it might not be faster, because the script uses a Python loop over the `covs` array to call `sqrtm` for each covariance matrix.  If performance is critical, test with your actual data.

Answer (score 0):

Since I did not find the answer anywhere and I needed just one calculation of `pdf(X)` for each `mean, std` pair.

I vectorized directly from the formula (so it only works for `pdf` (but other functions can be written similarly):

```py
lpi = (2*np.pi)**3
def vectorized_normal_pdf(X, means, stds):
    ndev = (X - means)/stds
    exp = (ndev[:,None,:] @ (X - means)[:,:,None]).squeeze()
    return np.exp(-0.5*exp)/np.sqrt(lpi*stds.prod(axis=1))
```

where, 
all `X`, `means`, `stds` are of shape `[N, d]` (N multivariate data points with d values each)
and the output is `[N]`

I have verified that it gives the correct answer (within a small error of 1e-14, I don't know why it is not equal, maybe they are using some numerical stability thing by adding a small epsilon in division) 
and is **much** faster (with size of just 10^4 I got **~4300x** speedup):

```py
X = np.random.rand(10000, 3)
means = np.random.rand(10000, 3)
stds = np.random.rand(10000, 3)

>>> %timeit norm_pdf(X, means, stds)
684 µs ± 12.7 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

>>> %timeit [multivariate_normal(means[i], stds[i]).pdf(X[i]) for i in range(10000)]
2.94 s ± 207 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

>>> ( (res1 - res2) < 1e-14 ).all()
True
```

This is crucial for applications like Gaussian Mixture Models applied to images, as we need multiple Gaussians for each pixel process, so for a very small/low-res 240*320 image it is 76800 Gaussians.

***Note that this does not handle covariance matrices (yet) but usually you can just use stds instead of the whole matrix***