# NumPy: simultaneous sampling from multivariate Gaussians with matrix of means

Tags: performance, numpy

I have an `N` by `P` matrix in which in which the `n`-th row is a `P`-vector representing the mean for a multivariate Gaussian and a `P` by `P` matrix `Sigma` representing a shared covariance matrix.

Is there any way to sample from all `N` multivariate Gaussians in NumPy faster than using a for loop?

```
Normal = np.random.multivariate_normal

for n in range(N):
    X[n] = Normal(mean=mu[n], cov=Sigma)
```

Comment: This looks like a  duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49681124/vectorized-implementation-for-numpy-random-multivariate-normal (but simpler, because you have just one covariance matrix).